# Right Angles in a Triangle

Tags: geometry, euclidean-geometry, triangles

Let $ABC$ be a triangle and $D$ a point on its interior so that $DBC = 60°$ and $DCB = DAB = 30°$. If $M$ and $N$ are the middlepoint of $AC$ and $BC$, respectively, show that $DMN = 90°$

I know that $DBN$ is an equilateral triangle, that $BD = DN = BN = NC$, $NDC = NCD = 30°$, but I'm stuck at this point.

Comment: Maybe it helps that angle $DBA=ADC$?

Comment: Are you sure $\angle{DBC}=60^o$? or is it rather $\angle{BDC}=60^o$?

Answer (score 1):

Let $C'$ be the reflection of $C$ about $D$. Point $A$ lies on the circle of diameter $BC'$.

But $NM\parallel AB$, because $M$ and $N$ are the midpoints of $CA$ and $CB$; and $ND\parallel BC'$, because $D$ and $N$ are the midpoints of $CC'$ and $CB$. It follows that $\angle DMN=\angle C'AB=90°$, QED.

[image]

Comment: thank you so much, that's such a good answer

Answer (score 0):

[image]

Considering figure,triangle ABF is right angled at C. CH is median and $\angle CHD=120^o$. Also $\angle DEC$ is opposite to $\angle HFC $ in cyclic quadrilateral DECF so it's measure is $120^o$. In this way quadrilateral DECH is parallelogram and $DH||EC$ or $AD||EC$ therefore:

$\angle MCE=\angle DAM$

$\angle DMA=\angle EMC$

$\Rightarrow \triangle AMD=\triangle CME\Rightarrow DM=ME$

for ASA, that is M is midpoint of DE so MN is radius of the circle which deduces that $\angle DMN=90^o$.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca, You are right. I will work more on it.

Comment: @Intelligentipauca, +1, your solution is excellent.